# Point in polygon program

Tags: c, polygon, point

So I'm very new in programming in C and I've been trying to make a program that would tell me if some point is inside a polygon or not, based on existing algorithm. I want the program to ask me for input data and give me the result ( 0 or 1 )I made something, but I'm kinda stuck at the end and don't know how to make this work and finish it.
I don't have any errors, I'm not getting any output. It asks me to enter the needed values and in the end it doesn't return what it's supposed to ( In or out; 0 or 1

```
int main() {
    int n, s, d, vertx[6], verty[6], testx, testy, i, j, c = 0;
    printf("Enter the number of vertices of the polygon\n");
    scanf("%d", &n);

    printf("Enter the x coordinates of the polygon\n");
     for (s = 0; s < n; s++)
        scanf("%d", &vertx[6]);

    printf("Enter the y coordinates of the polygon\n");
        for(d = 0; d < n; d++)
            scanf("%d", &verty[6]);

    printf("Enter the x and y test coordinates\n");
    scanf("%d%d", &testx, &testy);

    for (i = 0, j = n-1; i < n; j = i++) {
       if ( ((verty[i]>testy) != (verty[j]>testy)) &&
          (testx < (vertx[j]-vertx[i]) * (testy-verty[i]) / (verty[j]-                             verty[i]) + vertx[i]) )
   c = !c;
  }
  return c;
  printf("%d", &c);
  }
```

I hope there is someone willing to help me a little bit with this. 
Thank you!

Comment: You need to specify the problem.  Are there errors, are you getting incorrect output, etc.

Comment: I don't have any errors, I'm not getting any output. It asks me to enter the needed values and in the end it doesn't return what it's supposed to ( In or out; 0 or 1)

Answer (score 1):

Please look closely at your scanf statements. You want to scan to a different entry in the array each time, but you are scanning into a location past the end of your array's memory!